# javascript regex to ignore sub directories for chokidar

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, fs

Currently using Chokidar to do file watching on a file structure.  I have a requirement to watch a specific directory, but ignore any sub-directories created in that directory.

For example,
`/var/app/current/somedir`

I would watch any **file** created in *somedir*.  However if a **directory** were created in *somedir*, then I want to ignore it recursively, thus also ignoring anything else created under it.

```
chokidar.watch(configuration.theDir, {
        ignored: `/\\var\\app\\current\\somedir\\<match anything here, except other directories!>\\<anything here would be ignored and further down...>/`,
        awaitWriteFinish: {
            stabilityThreshold: 2000,
            pollInterval: 100
        }
}).on('add', (file, details) => {
    // console.log(file, path);
});
```

The struggle is real for me to figure out how to properly implement a regex to do this.  Unfortunately the directories that get created are random and the name is not known beforehand.  Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex expression will match everything that **is a directory or belongs in a subdirectory** of the base (directory defined by a following slash `/`).

For your example, the base is: `/var/app/current/somedir`

Regex: `/^\/var\/app\/current\/somedir\/.*[\/].*$/i`

Test:

```
var tests = [
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.txt',
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder/',
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder/ssads/sad.s',
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.sd/sdasda.asda/',
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.txt',
    '/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder'
]

for (var ii = 0, nn = tests.length; ii < nn; ii++)
{
    if (/^\/var\/app\/current\/somedir\/.*[\/].*$/i.test(tests[ii]))
    {
        console.log('"'+tests[ii]+'"', 'Matched, so ignored.');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('"'+tests[ii]+'"', 'Not matched, so watch.');
    }
}
```

Prints the following in JavaScript console:

```
/*
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.txt" Not matched, so watch.
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder/" Matched, so ignored.
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder/ssads/sad.s" Matched, so ignored.
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.sd/sdasda.asda/" Matched, so ignored.
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder.txt" Not matched, so watch.
 * "/var/app/current/somedir/fileOrFolder" Not matched, so watch.
*/
```